# Problema al obtener la ubicación con google chrome Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-api

Tengo el siguiente código el cual se encarga de la ubicación geográfica de latitud, longitud y el mapa de donde uno se encuentra:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>javascript-mobile-desktop-geolocation With No Simulation with Google Maps</title>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">      

<style>
    body {font-family: Helvetica;font-size:11pt;padding:0px;margin:0px}
    #title {background-color:#e22640;padding:5px;}
    #current {font-size:10pt;padding:5px;}  
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initialiseMap();initialise()">
    <h1>Ubicación con GPS</h1>
    <div id="current">Initializing...</div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:320px; height:350px"></div>

    <script src="js/geoPosition.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
    function initialiseMap()
    {
        var myOptions = {
              zoom: 4,
              mapTypeControl: true,
              mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
              navigationControl: true,
              navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP      
            }   
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    }
    function initialise()
    {
        if(geoPosition.init())
        {
            document.getElementById('current').innerHTML="Receiving...";
            geoPosition.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,function(){document.getElementById('current').innerHTML="Couldn't get location"},{enableHighAccuracy:true});
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('current').innerHTML="Functionality not available";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(p)
    {
        var latitude = parseFloat( p.coords.latitude );
        var longitude = parseFloat( p.coords.longitude );
        document.getElementById('current').innerHTML="latitude=" + latitude + " longitude=" + longitude;
        var pos=new google.maps.LatLng( latitude , longitude);
        map.setCenter(pos);
        map.setZoom(14);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<strong>yes</strong>"
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map,
            title:"You are here"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

el archivo geoPosition.js:

```
var bb = { 
    success: 0,
    error: 0,
    blackberryTimeoutId : -1
};

function handleBlackBerryLocationTimeout()
{
if(bb.blackberryTimeoutId!=-1) {
    bb.error({ message:     "Timeout error", 
               code:        3
           });
}
}
function handleBlackBerryLocation()
{
    clearTimeout(bb.blackberryTimeoutId);
    bb.blackberryTimeoutId=-1;
    if (bb.success && bb.error) {
            if(blackberry.location.latitude==0 && blackberry.location.longitude==0) {
                    //http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_unavailable_error
                    //POSITION_UNAVAILABLE (numeric value 2)
                    bb.error({message:"Position unavailable", code:2});
            }
            else
            {  
                    var timestamp=null;
                    //only available with 4.6 and later
                    //http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/8861/blackberry_location_568404_11.jsp
                    if (blackberry.location.timestamp)
                    {
                            timestamp = new Date( blackberry.location.timestamp );
                    }
                    bb.success( { timestamp:    timestamp , 
                                  coords: { 
                                        latitude:  blackberry.location.latitude,
                                        longitude: blackberry.location.longitude
                                    }
                                });
            }
            //since blackberry.location.removeLocationUpdate();
            //is not working as described http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/8861/blackberry_location_removeLocationUpdate_568409_11.jsp
            //the callback are set to null to indicate that the job is done

            bb.success = null;
            bb.error = null;
    }
}

 var geoPosition=function() {

    var pub = {};
    var provider=null;
    var u="undefined";
    var ipGeolocationSrv = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=JSONPCallback';

    pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success,error,opts)
    {
            provider.getCurrentPosition(success, error,opts);
    }

    pub.jsonp = {
        callbackCounter: 0,

        fetch: function(url, callback) {
            var fn = 'JSONPCallback_' + this.callbackCounter++;
            window[fn] = this.evalJSONP(callback);
            url = url.replace('=JSONPCallback', '=' + fn);

            var scriptTag = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
            scriptTag.src = url;
            document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
        },

        evalJSONP: function(callback) {
            return function(data) {
                callback(data);
            }
        }
    };

    pub.confirmation = function()
    {
        return confirm('This Webpage wants to track your physical location.\nDo you allow it?');
    };

    pub.init = function()
    {                                   
        try
        {
            var hasGeolocation = typeof(navigator.geolocation)!=u;
            if( !hasGeolocation ){
                if( !pub.confirmation() ){
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if ( ( typeof(geoPositionSimulator)!=u ) && (geoPositionSimulator.length > 0 ) ){
                    provider=geoPositionSimulator;
            } else if (typeof(bondi)!=u && typeof(bondi.geolocation)!=u  ) {
                    provider=bondi.geolocation;
            } else if ( hasGeolocation ) {
                    provider=navigator.geolocation;
                    pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error, opts) {
                            function _success(p) {
                                    //for mozilla geode,it returns the coordinates slightly differently
                                    var params;
                                    if(typeof(p.latitude)!=u) {
                                            params = {
                                                timestamp: p.timestamp, 
                                                coords: {
                                                    latitude:  p.latitude,
                                                    longitude: p.longitude
                                                }
                                            };
                                    } else {
                                            params = p;
                                    }
                                    success( params );
                            }
                            provider.getCurrentPosition(_success,error,opts);
                    }
            } else if(typeof(window.blackberry)!=u && blackberry.location.GPSSupported) {
                    // set to autonomous mode
                    if(typeof(blackberry.location.setAidMode)==u) {
                        return false;                                   
                    }
                    blackberry.location.setAidMode(2);
                    //override default method implementation
                    pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success,error,opts)
                    {
                            //passing over callbacks as parameter didn't work consistently
                            //in the onLocationUpdate method, thats why they have to be set outside
                            bb.success = success;
                            bb.error = error;
                            //function needs to be a string according to
                            //http://www.tonybunce.com/2008/05/08/Blackberry-Browser-Amp-GPS.aspx
                            if(opts['timeout']) {
                                bb.blackberryTimeoutId = setTimeout("handleBlackBerryLocationTimeout()",opts['timeout']);
                            } else {
                                //default timeout when none is given to prevent a hanging script
                                bb.blackberryTimeoutId = setTimeout("handleBlackBerryLocationTimeout()",60000);
                            }                                       

 blackberry.location.onLocationUpdate("handleBlackBerryLocation()");
                            blackberry.location.refreshLocation();
                    }
                    provider = blackberry.location;             

            } else if ( typeof(Mojo) !=u && typeof(Mojo.Service.Request)!="Mojo.Service.Request") {
                    provider = true;
                    pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error, opts) {
                        parameters = {};
                        if( opts ) {
                             //http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1673#GPS-getCurrentPosition
                             if (opts.enableHighAccuracy && opts.enableHighAccuracy == true ){
                                    parameters.accuracy = 1;
                             }
                             if ( opts.maximumAge ) {
                                    parameters.maximumAge = opts.maximumAge;
                             }
                             if (opts.responseTime) {
                                    if( opts.responseTime < 5 ) {
                                            parameters.responseTime = 1;
                                    } else if ( opts.responseTime < 20 ) {
                                            parameters.responseTime = 2;
                                    } else {
                                            parameters.timeout = 3;
                                    }
                             }
                    }

                     r = new Mojo.Service.Request( 'palm://com.palm.location' , {
                            method:"getCurrentPosition",
                                parameters:parameters,
                                onSuccess: function( p ){
                                    success( { timestamp: p.timestamp, 
                                               coords: {
                                                    latitude:  p.latitude, 
                                                    longitude: p.longitude,
                                                    heading:   p.heading
                                                }
                                            });
                                },
                                onFailure: function( e ){
                                                    if (e.errorCode==1) {
                                                        error({ code:       3,
                                                                message:    "Timeout"
                                                            });
                                                    } else if (e.errorCode==2){
                                                        error({ code:       2,
                                                                message:    "Position unavailable" 
                                                            });
                                                    } else {
                                                        error({ code:       0,
                                                                message:    "Unknown Error: webOS-code" + errorCode 
                                                            });
                                                    }
                                            }
                                });
                    }

            }
            else if (typeof(device)!=u && typeof(device.getServiceObject)!=u) {
                    provider=device.getServiceObject("Service.Location", "ILocation");

                    //override default method implementation
                    pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error, opts){
                            function callback(transId, eventCode, result) {
                                if (eventCode == 4) {
                                    error({message:"Position unavailable", code:2});
                                } else {
                                    //no timestamp of location given?
                                    success( {  timestamp:null, 
                                                coords: {
                                                        latitude:   result.ReturnValue.Latitude, 
                                                        longitude:  result.ReturnValue.Longitude, 
                                                        altitude:   result.ReturnValue.Altitude,
                                                        heading:    result.ReturnValue.Heading }
                                            });
                                }
                            }
                    //location criteria

                    var criteria = new Object();
                    criteria.LocationInformationClass = "BasicLocationInformation";
                    //make the call
                    provider.ILocation.GetLocation(criteria,callback);
                    }
            } else  {                            
                    pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error, opts) {
                            pub.jsonp.fetch(ipGeolocationSrv, 
                                    function( p ){ success( { timestamp: p.timestamp, 
                                                               coords: { 
                                                                    latitude:   p.latitude, 
                                                                    longitude:  p.longitude,
                                                                    heading:    p.heading
                                                                }
                                                            });});
                    }
                    provider = true;
            }
        }
        catch (e){ 
            if( typeof(console) != u ) console.log(e);                  
            return false;
        }
        return  provider!=null;
    }
    return pub;
}();
```

En internet explorer me funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo pruebo en google Chrome me muestra la ubicación de otra ciudad cercana a mi región.
Me gustaría poder resolver, y que me permita mostrar mi ubicación correcta en google chrome.

He notado que en internet explorer se demora unos segundos mas en cargar para visualizar la ubicación, quizas en el google chrome le falta alguna limpieza de pre carga o alguna compatibilidad.

**Mi objetivo es poder obtener mi ubicación con el mapa de forma exacta en distinto browsers con javascript o algun codigo de tipo del lado del cliente.**

Si alguien sabe, desde ya, le agradezco su atención.

Answer (score 1):

Falta usar `enableHighAccuracy: true`, que es una propiedad Boolean que indica que la aplicación desea recibir los mejores resultados posibles asi que se debe modificar el objeto `myOptions`

```
var myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
```

Comment: gracias por responder @x-rw , pero sigue igual. En la consola de inspección del navegador me dice; 
util.js:224 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
tambien dice:
util.js:224 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required
No se si esto es relevante para saber el problema

Comment: @Danilo hice la prueba y funciona al igual que en edge

Comment: que extraño, quizas sea mi computador, me llama bastante la atención que en IE funciona correctamente, pero en Chrome me muestre otra ubicación. En mozilla lo probe y me muestra lo mismo que en Chrome

Comment: @Danilo probe tu codigo sin modificar y si efectivamente en chrome mostraba otra direccion, luego probe con los cambios de mi respuesta y ahora muestra la direccion exacta

Comment: mmmm, que extraño, sigue igual, quizas hay alguna configuración que habrá que habilitar en el google chrome